# OpenCL Kernel working fine on intel but not on nvdia GPU?

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl, nvidia, intel

My application uses OpenCL. I tested on my machine it was working fine but on a user's machine the kernels are just not working.

**My Machine**:

```
OpenCL Status : Using OpenCL Platform : Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
OpenCL Status : Using GPU Device : Intel(R) HD Graphics 510
```

**Users Machine**:

```
OpenCL Status : Using OpenCL Platform : NVIDIA CUDA
OpenCL Status : Using GPU Device : GeForce GT 730
```

**Code C++**

```
kernels = new ComputeKernel();
std::string source = ReadShaderSourceFile(GetExecutableDir() + "\\Data\\kernels\\generators\\generators.cl", &tmp);
    kernels->AddSoruce(source);
    kernels->BuildProgram("-I" + appState->globals.kernelsIncludeDir + " -cl-fast-relaxed-math -cl-mad-enable");
    kernels->AddKernel("clear_mesh_terrain");
kernels->CreateBuffer("mesh", CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, appState->models.customBase->mesh->vertexCount * sizeof(Vert));
        kernels->WriteBuffer("mesh", true, appState->models.customBase->mesh->vertexCount * sizeof(Vert), appState->models.customBase->mesh->vert);
kernels->SetKernelArg("clear_mesh_terrain", 0, "mesh");

        kernels->ExecuteKernel("clear_mesh_terrain", cl::NDRange(1), 

cl::NDRange(appState->models.coreTerrain->mesh->vertexCount));
```

The ComputeKernel class:

```
void ComputeKernel::AddSoruce(std::string source)
{
    sources.push_back({source.c_str(), source.size()});
}

void ComputeKernel::BuildProgram(std::string options)
{
    program = cl::Program(context, sources);

    if (program.build({ device }, options.c_str()) != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        onStatus("Error Building : " + program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device));
        return;
    }
}

void ComputeKernel::AddKernel(std::string name)
{
    kernels[name] = cl::Kernel(program, name.c_str());
}

void ComputeKernel::Clear()
{
    sources.clear();
    kernels.clear();
}

void ComputeKernel::ExecuteKernel(std::string name, cl::NDRange local, cl::NDRange global)
{
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernels[name], cl::NullRange, global, local);
    queue.finish();
}

void ComputeKernel::CreateBuffer(std::string name, int type, size_t size)
{
    OpenCLBuffer buffer;
    buffer.size = size;
    buffer.buffer = cl::Buffer(context, type, size);
    buffers[name] = buffer;
}

void ComputeKernel::SetKernelArg(std::string name, int arg, std::string buffer)
{
    kernels[name].setArg(arg, buffers[buffer].buffer);
}

void ComputeKernel::ReadBuffer(std::string buffer, bool blocking, size_t size, void* data)
{
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffers[buffer].buffer, blocking ? CL_TRUE : CL_FALSE, 0, size, data);
}

void ComputeKernel::WriteBuffer(std::string buffer, bool blocking, size_t size, void* data)
{
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffers[buffer].buffer, blocking ? CL_TRUE : CL_FALSE, 0, size, data);
}
```

The Kernel:

```
__kernel void clear_mesh_terrain(__global Vert* mesh)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    mesh[i].normal.x = 0.0f;
    mesh[i].normal.y = 0.0f;
    mesh[i].normal.z = 0.0f;
    mesh[i].normal.w = 0.0f;
    mesh[i].position.y = 0.0f;

}
```

Now by not working i mean nothing is hapenning at all(kernels are not getting executed at all) but there are no errors no compile failure of kernels.

Comment: IIRC the GeForce GT 730 doesn't actually support OpenCL at all.

Comment: I have access to  GT 730 and it supports OpenCL.
Also, since the status message above is getting printed OpenCL driver is there.
Please try and catch exception and print the corresponding error code and string to get more information on the issue, as supported by C++ binding of OpenCL.

Comment: @AquaAsh i dont think there are any errors. What i saw from nvdia offical spec GT 730 supports OpenCL 1.1 and i am using OpenCL 2.0

Comment: Try if it works if you don't use the struct `Vert` and instead only use simple `float3`/`float4` data types.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX Vert is just a combination of 4 float4 and its working fine on my machine

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you are running out of memory on your Nvidia GT 730. Some of the Buffers fail to allocate, the Kernel runs through with 0 execution time and yet does nothing.

Keep track of how much memory you allocate in total. It should still work with smaller Buffers.

Comment: This works on my machine with no dedicated GPU (VRAM is shared from main ram about 100 something MB ) so i dont think its problem with memory. And a Dedicated GPU should have more memory

Comment: The GT 730 has only 2GB of dedicated memory and no shared memory. The Intel HD 510 likely has more memory available (in the form of shared system memory); usually half of the system memory, so 4GB if it is 8GB of system memory.

Comment: I have only 4GB system memory. Visual Studio takes up 600-700MB Chrome another 400MB OS about 1GB about 2.5 - 2.8 GB Free at max Still its running good. And i am not using much memory at all. the default mesh uses about 4 - 5 MB